# How to access a key => value in an associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'MenuItemReview' => array(
            'menu_item_id' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'avgRating' => '4.0000'
        )
    )
)
```

I'm trying to get access the value of avgRating.

Comment: Have you tried the _first_ place to look for such information — the [PHP documentation](http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? Since they actually have a very specific example for accessing multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code loads your data into `$array` and finally sets `$avgRating` to what you want.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'MenuItemReview' => array(
            'menu_item_id' => '1'
        ),
        0 => array(
            'avgRating' => '4.0000'
        )
    )
);
$avgRating = $array[0][0]['avgRating'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason i thought i would have to right a complex foreach loop. thanks again,

Answer (score 2):

If you load that multidimensional array into the variable $arr, you would access the `avgRating` value by typing `$arr[0][0]['avgRating']`.